# How do I retrieve text from an html element?

Tags: elm

How do I get the caption from a button?

```
decorateOn : String -> Html Msg -> Html Msg
decorateOn selectedCaption button =

    if button.text == selectedCaption then
        button [ class "selectedNavigationButton" ] []
    else
        button [ class "navigationButton" ] []
```

> `button` does not have a field named `text`. - The type of `button`
>   is:
>
> ```
> Html Home.Msg
> ```
>
> Which does not contain a field named `text`.

Note, I realize that the "button" is really of type Html Msg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn your thinking on its head. Rather than seeing what is in the button text, you need to set the text at the same stage as setting the class. So that gives you something like

```
decorateOn : String -> Html Msg -> Html Msg
decorateOn selectedCaption button =    
    if selectedCaption == "the selected value" then
        button [ class "selectedNavigationButton" ] [text selectedCaption ]
    else
        button [ class "navigationButton" ] [text selectedCaption]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the text from a button without resorting to hacks involving ports and JavaScript. Moreover, you can't really inspect anything about the Elm Virtual DOM from within Elm.

Instead, try to refactor your app so that you can get the information from your model.